# Improve read XML string in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the xml string sends to SP as nvarchar(Max)

```
'<Devices><ID value="13" /><ID value="39" /></Devices>'
```

And I use this way to return IDs

```
DECLARE @DeviceIDs nvarchar(max) = N'<Devices><ID value="13" /><ID value="39" /></Devices>'
       ,@iDevice INT;
DECLARE @Devices table (DeviceId int PRIMARY KEY)
                EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iDevice OUTPUT, @DeviceIDs
                Insert Into @Devices(DeviceId)
                SELECT value FROM OPENXML (@iDevice, '/Devices/ID',3) WITH (value int)
                EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @iDevice 

SELECT * FROM @Devices
```

The previous code working fine, But the sp_xml_preparedocument is extended stored procedure and  according to technet.microsoft.com : This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server [Extended Stored Procedures](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

How I can get this Ids without change xml structure

Comment: Saving your XML to an XML-typed column instead of an NVARCHAR column would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak , but I have a big project working on this approach

Comment: Then I can only suggest that you wait for that project to finish. Working with XML efficiently requires XML-typed columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) types and [related XML methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190798.aspx) [`.node`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188282.aspx) / [`.value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178030.aspx) to achieve this.

```
DECLARE @DeviceIDs XML = N'<Devices><ID value="13" /><ID value="39" /></Devices>'
SELECT  c.value('@value','int') as DeviceID
FROM @DeviceIDs.nodes('Devices/ID') as t(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ughai I am use your way but I convert the nvarchar to xml

```
DECLARE @DeviceIDsStr nvarchar(max) = N'<Devices><ID value="13" /><ID value="39" /></Devices>';
DECLARE @DeviceIDs XML = CAST(@DeviceIDsStr AS XML) ;
SELECT  c.value('@value','int') as DeviceID
FROM @DeviceIDs.nodes('Devices/ID') as t(c)
```